# ArangoDb get latest document from all collections

Tags: arangodb, aql, nosql

I'm beginning to think I've modeled my data a bit incorrectly, since I'm having trouble querying it.

Currently what I have is a bunch of Customers (modeled as a Database per customer)
These Customers have a bunch of Devices: Device1...n (modeled as a collection per device)
These devices generate messages (modeled as documents within the device collection).

In order to give good feedback to customers, I now want to support retrieving a customers latest messages (one message per device).

I'm having trouble to find documentation describing how to query over multiple collections, as there can be 1000s of devices for a customer, I'd rather not do 1000s of queries.

Thanks!

Comment: Why does a customer need to know the latest messages for thousands of devices? Can't you deliver the latest message per device incrementally as the customer requests them? (e.g. infinite scrolling with dynamic loading and unloading of data, or a simple pagination)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there can be 1000s of devices per customer, and device messages are stored in device-specific collections, searching for the latest message for a customer would require you to find the *latest* record in a variable number of collections, which will not only hard to express in a query but also inefficient.

Is it possible to put the messages of all devices for a given customer into a single customer-specific collection, and store the device id as an attribute in each document?

For example:

```
// create customer-specific collections
db._create("messages_customer1");
db._create("messages_customer2");

// create an index on `dt` attribute in each collection 
// so messages can be queried efficiently sorted by date
db.messages_customer1.ensureIndex({ type: "skiplist", fields: [ "dt" ]});
db.messages_customer2.ensureIndex({ type: "skiplist", fields: [ "dt" ]});

// insert some messages for customer 1
db.messages_customer1.insert({ device: 123, dt: Date.now(), message: "foo" });
db.messages_customer1.insert({ device: 123, dt: Date.now(), message: "bar" });
db.messages_customer1.insert({ device: 456, dt: Date.now(), message: "baz" });

// insert some messages for customer 2
db.messages_customer2.insert({ device: 999, dt: Date.now(), message: "qux" });
db.messages_customer2.insert({ device: 888, dt: Date.now(), message: "wut" });
```

Now it will be relatively easy to find the latest message for a given customer:

- determine customer id via request and or business logic
- with customer id (e.g. id `1`), query customer-specific collection

For example:

```
var query = "FOR m IN @@messages SORT m.dt DESC LIMIT 1 RETURN m";
var id = 1;
var params = { "@messages": "messages_customer" + id }
latestMessage = db._query(query, params).toArray()[0];
```

If the messages are all that's customer-specific, then there's also no need to create separate databases per customer, as all customer-specific collections could go into the same database. You should of course care about access control to the data, either via application business logic or [Foxx](https://docs.arangodb.com/Foxx/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The separation of devices as their own collections was to leverage the auto increment id. Is there some way to keep that with this solution? Also, there might be thousands of devices that create tens of thousands of messages. Will there be an issue with the number of docs within one collection?

Comment: You may get away without an auto-increment id. Each document in ArangoDB has a `_key` attribute, which will be filled with some value automatically when not being provided by the client application. Though that server-generated is predictable for the client application, it will enable you to access each document via its unique `_key` later. And if you keep message time in some other attribute, then you can still find the *latest* messages relatively easily. Another obstacle when using `_key` for retrieving messages by date is that the index on `_key` is a hash index (i.e. unsorted).

Comment: If there are clients which will have lots of messages, then this would mean collections with many documents inside. It may help to limit the total amount of messages per collection, e.g. by using a cap constraint in ArangoDB. But I am not sure if your business case allows that. If not, then probably the multi-collection option (one per device) may be the better choice, but that will not allow you to find the *latest* message that easily. You will then have to check each client-specific message collection for the latest entry.